# change location of buttons in panel

Tags: c#, button

I have a panel that there is some buttons in it. I want that if the panel size change, the buttons location change too.

for example if the panel decrese 5px, the buttons location x decrese 5 px to...

how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: if you use WinForms see about [Anchor property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ Grundy thanks, I used anchor but it change the size only. I want to change the location too...

Comment: it depends how you use anchors, can you provide more information?

Comment: dock the button somewhere in the panel (see Anchor property)

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor property to define how a control is automatically resized as its parent control is resized.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms:
Using Anchor property you will be able to resize the button as the panel is resized. But if you need to change location then I'm afraid you have to do it in code, e.g. when on resize event of your form. The sample below will position the button on the 10th of the form width.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.Location = new Point(this.Width / 10, this.button1.Location.Y);
}
```

WPF:
In WPF you can do it in XAML using grid with two columns. You place the button in the second column. The first column will work as a kind of buffer to keep the button away from the edge of the application. One think - size of the columns has to be described as a ratio, that is use star notation ("*"). In code below the button is always at 10th of the grid width

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Anchor`  or `Dock` properties of the button
This [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/) may help you